# Check within 3 variables that 3 specified values are held, in any order but not doubled up

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a function into my card game to check if the first 2 cards hold any 2 out of the following 3 values: `6`, `7` or `8`
i.e. `6&7`, `7&8`, or `6&8`.

For the sake of being specific: I **don't want** it to `return true` if its 2 of the same value but I imagine that could be done with a `&& card1Value!==card2Value` added onto the conditions of the logical statement.

From there I'll then need to make it so that card3Value is checked for the missing value.

Comment: If you have started to code, share your progress.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally split that up a little:

```
function threeCardsAreValid(card1, card2, card3) {

 if(!twoCardsAreValid(card1, card2)) return false
 if (cardIs6Or7Or8(card3) && card3 !== card1 && card3!== card2) return true
 return false
}

function twoCardsAreValid(card1, card2) {

 if (cardIs6Or7Or8(card1) && cardIs6Or7Or8(card2) && card1 !== card2) {
  return true
 }
 return false

}

function cardIs6Or7Or8(card) {
 return (card === 6 | card === 7 | card === 8)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would personnaly go for is `filtering the array` and `creating a set` to see if there are no duplicates.

Then, if the result array has a length greater than 2, then at least 2 of the 3 cards are valid.

```js
function checkHand(card1, card2, card3){
  const arr = [card1,card3,card2]
  const validHands = [6,7,8]
  
  const validHandsFilteredWithoutDuplicates =  [...new Set(arr.filter(x => validHands.includes(x)))]
  
  return validHandsFilteredWithoutDuplicates.length >= 2
}

console.log(checkHand(6,7,9)) // true
console.log(checkHand(1,2,3)) // false
console.log(checkHand(7,7,4)) // false
console.log(checkHand(6,7,8)) // true
```